# Is there any way to automate the functions of instruments?

Tags: ios, instruments

I'm using instruments to measure the performance of my app. I need to do it regularly. So I don't want to test manually. Is there any way it could be automated??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the same template all the time, such as the Time Profiler, you can edit the scheme to use that template when you profile your project. Choose a template from the Instrument menu.

[image: Scheme Editor Profile step]

When you choose Product > Profile in Xcode, Instruments will start profiling the project automatically without you having to choose a template or click the Record button.

Any further automation, if possible, requires scripting, of which I have no solution for you.

Comment: That was helpful.. But I need to know whether XCTest could be integrated with Instruments for automation?

Comment: I do not know of any way to automatically profile an app in Instruments from a unit test. XCTest does have support for performance tests to measure the performance of a chunk of code. Create a new unit test class and you can see an example of a performance test.